# Proof for $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v} = \| \mathbf{v} \|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Anyone have a good link for proving $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v} = \| \mathbf{v} \|^2$?

I tried [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/) but the site doesn't seem to be responding right now.

Comment: Just use the definition.

Comment: What is your definition of $\cdot$? And the definition of $\Vert \cdot \Vert$?

Comment: Generally I take that as the definition of $\| \cdot \|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $\textbf{v} = \left [ \begin{array}{c}
v_1 \\
\vdots \\
v_n \\
\end{array} \right ]$.  Then

$$
\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{v} \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
v_1 & \ldots & v_n \\
\end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c}
v_1 \\
\vdots \\
v_n \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; v_1^2 + \ldots + v_n^2 \;\; =\;\; ||\textbf{v}||^2.
$$

I'm assuming that you meant in a finite-dimensional vector space, correct?